# Corrupt XFS after power failure in Virtual Machine

Tags: centos-7, xfs

One of our servers failed and when it came back to life, one of the hosted VMs [CentOS 7] had issues with XFS.

- There are 3 volumes, `root`, `/swap` and `/home`, and I was able to `xfs_repair` the `root` volume, but something is still not functioning properly.

When I boot the server normally after fixing `root`, it is somewhat functional and I can see the 3 volumes; I know some stuff is not working, with `dmesg` displaying xfs errors.

When I boot in emergency mode, I can only see `/dev/mapper/cl-root` and `/dev/mapper/cl-swap`.

- I can't find `home` anywhere, and I also checked `/dev/dm-X` - there is only `0` and `1`, matching `root` and `swap`.

  - Why can't I see `home`? Can I go into emergency mode and fix it in a different way?
- With `swap`, if I try to `xfs_repair`, it errors with `could not find valid secondary superblock`, and I am not sure if this is related to the fact I can't see `home`.

  - Can I fix `swap` in a different way, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

1) There is nothing to fix in swap, just run mkswap on it. It's not a file system, it's a raw block device with just swap header on it.

2) Look through the output of `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay`, and see what volumes are present. If the home volume headers are toast you may be out of luck without forensic data recovery.

Are you sure that home was on the same disk? Do root and swap add up to the full size of the disk? It is possible that home was on an entirely separate disk that was at some point removed from the VM but the removal was pending a reboot because.

Comment: Yes, all volumes are in a single disk in proxmox. I am now trying to repair the home volume. If I start the machine regularly, it shows up. If I boot into emergency mode it doesn't. Does this indicate anything else?